# Why is faster to open a new socket for each communication that sharing same socket in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

I have an issue with socket related to reusing a Java socket for multiple requests rather that creating a new socket for each request.

I have created a simple example that consists of a socket server that accepts messages that consist of 2B payload length and payload. The accepted messages payloads are writted back to client (ECHO). When I use this server with a client that use only one socket it is approximetly 37 times slower than in case of a client that opens socket for each message. I am testing this on 1024B message for 100 times.

Only reason for this I can think of is that there is some flushing mechanism in socket close method that speed up communication.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Server:**

```
public class SocketServer {

    public static final int PORT = 12345;
    public static final int HEADER_LN = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        while (true) {
            final Socket client = server.accept();
            threadPool.submit(() -> {
                try (InputStream is = client.getInputStream()) {
                    while (true) {
                        byte[] header = read(is, HEADER_LN);
                        int payloadLn = payloadLn(header);
                        byte[] payload = read(is, payloadLn);
                        client.getOutputStream().write(header);
                        client.getOutputStream().write(payload);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static int payloadLn(byte[] header) {
        return (((header[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (header[1] & 0xFF)) - HEADER_LN;
    }

    static byte[] read(InputStream is, int bytes) throws IOException {
        byte[] result = new byte[bytes];
        int index = 0;
        while (index != bytes) {
            int readed = is.read(result, index, bytes - index);
            if (readed == -1) {
                throw new IOException("short input");
            }
            index += readed;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**Client:**

```
public class SocketClient {

    private static final int TEST_COUNT = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Random rand = new Random();
        final byte[] message = new byte[1024];
        rand.nextBytes(message);
        // header
        message[0] = (byte) ((message.length >> 8) & 0xFF);
        message[1] = (byte) (message.length & 0xFF);

        System.out.println("\nmultiple sockets:");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_COUNT; i++) {
            try (Socket sck = new Socket("localhost", SocketServer.PORT)) {
                handleComm(sck, message);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

        System.out.println("single socket:");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try (Socket sck = new Socket("localhost", SocketServer.PORT)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < TEST_COUNT; i++) {
                handleComm(sck, message);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
    }

    private static void handleComm(Socket sck, byte[] message) throws IOException {
        sck.getOutputStream().write(message);
        final byte[] echo = SocketServer.read(sck.getInputStream(), message.length);
        if (!Arrays.equals(echo, message)) {
            System.err.println("respone ko");
        }
    }

}
```

**Client output**

```
multiple sockets:
took: 107ms
single socket:
took: 3971ms
```

Comment: OK, I have explicitly closed each socket, but result is the same. Thanks anyway.